# Trouble using recursion to print out converging and diverging sequence of numbers

Tags: java, recursion

The wording of the problem is
"Write a method writeSequence that accepts an integer n as a parameter and prints a symmetric sequence of n numbers with descending integers ending in 1 followed by ascending integers beginning with 1, as in the table below:"

The table is essentially:

```
1 = 1
2 = 1 1
3 = 2 1 2
4 = 2 1 1 2
5 = 3 2 1 2 3
6 = 3 2 1 1 2 3
```

My attempted code is

```
public void writeSequence(int n){
    if (n < 1){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (n == 1){
        System.out.print(n + " ");
    }
    else if (n == 2){
        System.out.print(1 + " " + 1 + " ");
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0){
        System.out.print(n - (n/2) + " ");
        writeSequence(n - (n/2));
        System.out.print(n - (n/2) + " ");
    }
    else{
        System.out.print(n-(n/2) + " ");
        writeSequence(n - 2 );
        System.out.print(n-(n/2)+ " ");
    }
}
```

For inputs 1-10, my code is not generating the correct answer for 6, 8, and 10. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Fixed spelling in title

Edit 2:

My results are

```
1 = 1
2 = 1 1 
3 = 2 1 2
4 = 2 1 1 2
5 = 3 2 1 2 3
6 = 3 2 1 2 3 (wrong)
7 = 4 3 2 1 2 3 4
8 = 4 2 1 1 2 4 (wrong)
9 = 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5
10 = 5 3 2 1 2 3 5 (wrong)
```

If someone could show me where I have made an error in my code that would be great!

Comment: *my code is not generating the correct answer for 6, 8, and 10* - exactly what is it doing and what should it do?

Comment: I have added an edit at the end showing what my end table looks like vs. what it should look like!

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive call passes the incorrect value. Each time the algorithm recurses, it should decrease the value by `2`.

Change this:

```
writeSequence(n - (n/2));
```

to this:

```
writeSequence(n - 2);
```